# Testing dates for singleton

Tags: java, date, testing, singleton

I've always tested Dates in such way, that I had a protected method getDate() in my class, which I've overriden for test purposes. Example:

```
public class MyClass {
    protected Date getDate(){
        return new Date();
    };
}
```

Test:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(){
    @Override
    protected Date getDate(){ 
        return new Date(1234567890);
    }
};
```

That was enough to this day, but the following problem appeared:
I have a class that I want to instantiate once, so I use singleton pattern:

```
public static Something getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Something();
    }

    return instance;
}
```

The problem is that I have to create an object this way: Something.getInstance() - object is created inside that method. I cannot override getDate method inside getInstance, because it wouldnt make sense (sometimes I would need the real instance, sometimes test instance). This leads me to a question: How to test date in such situation?

Comment: Use any up-to-date mocking framework, like Powermock. That's the way to go today...

Comment: what you wanna do actually... ?

Comment: Which is you goal in testing dates? If you are just checking if the date is created properly, then you don't have to test them, they are already tested. Don't use the so-called `test-all` approach. Instead, if the dates somehow matter for your algorithm/method/whatsoever then you should think to use a mocking framework (like JMock, EasyMock, Mockito, Powermock and so on)

Answer (score 1):

As you just noticed every time you use plain-old-java singletons, you create untestable code.

There are other ways to have only one instance of a class. From simple - just create it once :) to using IoC frameworks like Spring to let them care about it.

I suggest you to take a look at [Misko Hevery's guide to writing testable code](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/), section about global state.

Comment: +1 for the link: always an interesting read ;-) and for the suggestion to kill the singleton before it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

If, and **only if** the Singleton pattern is not avoidable at any costs, you could mock the construction of the `Something` class using [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/):

```
//create mock instance,     
Something mockSomethingInstance = createMock(Something.class);
//create your Date instance to return
Date d = new Date();
when(mockSomethingInstance.getDate()).thenReturn(d);
```

You have to mock the constructor of the Something class, to always return the instance you created (**Beware** though, doing this will override all other constructions of the `Something` class too, but in this case, as this is a singleton, it seems OK.):

```
expectNew(Something.class).andReturn(mockSomethingInstance);
```

Also, [Powermock can mock static function calls too](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic), so you could mock the getInstance function on the `Something` class too:

```
//mock the static functions
mockStatic(Something.class);          

expect(Something.getInstance()).andReturn(mockSomethingInstance);
//have to replay the class in order to work
replay(IdGenerator.class);
```

However, I assume you want to do [partial mocking](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial), as you want to test the behavior of the class itself. But this is starting to get uglier and uglier...

**All in all:** think twice before using Singletons - as simple they seem (onlz seem, of course...), in the long run, they can quickly turn into nightmare... Using Spring is a much cleaner way of having the same, saving a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot (assumming that EasyMock would be an option) that you need to use Capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a getDate() method on your singleton then it has what's known as [global state](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI), which makes it almost impossible to mock up for testing purposes. Your only alternatives are to use a testing framework, or to change your class not to be a "true" singleton, while ensuring in other ways that only one instance of it can be instantiated. I'd argue that the latter option is the correct approach and you should not be using a singleton in this case.